# How to implement this validation in a Knockout-based form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I started to work on an ASP.NET MVC4 solution with the SPA template (Single Page Application).

The starting template manage some todo lists with a kind of post-it design.

I slightly modified the template this way:

- no more post-it design for dislaying elements
- but a table to list all elements + delete + edit button on each element
- at the end of the table: an add button

I have now the ability to edit one element in a form tag like this:

```
<form data-bind="with: currentTodoList, validate: true">
    <h1>Edition</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td><b data-bind="text: todoListId"></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User ID:</td>
            <td><input class="required" data-bind="value: userId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td><input class="required" data-bind="value: title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: category" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.saveTodoList">Save</button>
        <button data-bind="visible: todoListId, click: $parent.deleteTodoList">Delete</button>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.showGrid">Cancel</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

As you can see above, I set the validate data-binding on the form tag and I have some input element with the class required.

When I test this implementation it doesn't work as expected. Example:

- If I clear (empty) the userId field (which is required) I have a red validation message (picture 1). OK.
- If I fill this userId field again, the red validation messaged disappeared. OK.
- Then if I clear (empty) the title field (which is also required) I have the red validation message next to the userId field (picture 2). NOK.

[image]

[image]

The inverse is also true: `userId <--> title`. Any idea where is the problem?

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yksjesr1est5s69/MvcApplication6%20%283%29.zip) to download my test VS2012 solution to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the element that holds The red validation message? I do not see a span/div to display validation message in your form.

Comment: That's correct. I don't have any tag for validation message. I guest this is managed by the framework. Maybe that's not the right way to do?

Comment: I have used extenders to have such validations. I am not a knockout expert, but the example http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html talks about something similar to what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, I proceed like they suggest. That's why I need some help :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just to be clear on what I wanted to point from the example, there is a span against every field that displays the validation error message, and the visibility of this span is bound to the respective field's `hasError` field. Maybe you need something similar?

Comment: Maybe, I know this is how we proceed with standard MVC validation. But for knockout, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I played with your markup a little, with slight modification to the view model (not using a list, but editing a single entry).

Take a look at this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Zxjrb/1/

I have added a span for validation message for ID and User ID, skipped the span for Title and Category.

```
<span data-bind='visible: todoListId.hasError, text: todoListId.validationMessage'> </span>
```

You can see the messages coming up, when Id or UserId field being empty, and that not happening for the title/category fields.